# Java 13 Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

List.java:

```
package list;
public class List<T> {

private Node<T> first = null;

    public List () {
        this.first = new Node<T>(null);
    }
}
```

Node.java:

```
package list;
public class Node<T> {

    T data;
    Node<T> next = null;

    public Node(T t) {
        this.data = t;
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors while trying to compile:

```
List.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    private Node<T> first;
            ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class List<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class List

List.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        this.first = new Node<T>(null);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class List<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class List
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe the file structure of your application? Do you import `Node` in your `List` class? The error you show doesn't really relate to generics, java is saying that it cannot work out what you mean by `Node`

Comment: No, I'm not importing Node.
But I've put the two classes in the same package.

Comment: Have you compiled `Node`?

Comment: If your Node class is located in a different package, you have to import it. Normally the IDE helps you with problems like that.

Comment: Yes, I have a Node.class file in the same folder.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt Both of the classes are in the same package

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: Since both classes are in package `list`, both java source files must be in folder `list` and the classpath / sourcepath must be the parent folder of the `list` folder. Is that the case?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt using javac List.java and javac Node.java

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but perhaps it is something to do with Java 9 modules preventing your `Node` class being visible to `List`

Comment: @Andreas No, they are just in a folder called "Assignment"

Comment: @Lior Then move them to where I said, and try again. See [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/5221149) to question [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093928/5221149), and look at reasons #2b, #2a, and #3.

Comment: try to recompile. I would not suggest to to write `first = null;` as this is just its default value.